# UNION Has Quasi Duplicates. How to Select From Just One of the Tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Have 2 tables: Apples and Oranges. Each has the same structure -- 2 columns: Product and Price.

Thinking of it as a Venn Diagram in 3 roughly equal parts. So Apples and Oranges roughly share a third of the same data -- at least at the Product level. There are a small handful of records where the Product names are the same, but the Prices are different so they naturally slips through the UNION and creates 2 rows for those Products.

Now I'm just curious how to amend the UNION query so that in cases where the Product is the same, but the Prices are different, it would just use Apples.Price as the sole Price.

Will be using this UNION to join back to another table i.e.

```
WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM #Apples
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM #Oranges
    )
SELECT * FROM CTE c INNER JOIN Map m
    ON c.Product = m.Product
```

Sample Union Results:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|       PRODUCT       |      PRICE       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Jeans        |       50         | --from Apples
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Car          |       7500       | --from Oranges
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Phone        |       600        | --from Apples
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Phone        |       625        | --from Oranges
```

Would just want 3 rows, ideally, where the Phone at 600 is what's returned.

Comment: Please show sample data, expected results and existing union code.

Comment: Why do you need `NOLOCK` when you're querying a temporary table?

Comment: [Stop splattering hints everywhere](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidlean/2009/04/05/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could eliminate the overlapping products from the `Oranges` results with `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

```
WITH cte
  AS
  (
    SELECT * FROM @apples AS a
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM @oranges AS o
    WHERE
      NOT EXISTS
      (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM @apples AS a1  
        WHERE a1.product = o.product
      )
  )
SELECT
  *
FROM
  cte;
```

```
+---------+-------+
| product | price |
+---------+-------+
| car     |  7500 |
| jeans   |    50 |
| phone   |   625 |
+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Ah, was thinking of using a WHERE NOT EXISTS query instead of a UNION and working from there, but a WHERE NOT EXISTS in the UNION is even better. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are returning everything from both tables you could just use an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT 
            ISNULL(Apples.Product, Oranges.Product) AS Product,
            ISNULL(Apples.Price, Oranges.Price) AS Price
        FROM #Apples AS Apples
        FULL OUTER JOIN #Oranges AS Oranges
            ON Apples.Product = Oranges.Product        
    )
SELECT * FROM CTE c INNER JOIN Map m
    ON c.Product = m.Product
```

This will select everything from `#Apples` and `#Oranges`, but if there are overlapping products, then it will choose the price from `#Apples` over `#Oranges`. The `ISNULL` makes sure we get something back for each column in the "union" we are doing. Note that if the `Product` column is not unique in each table then you may still get duplicates in the result.

Comment: I might suggest coalesce vs isnull; but only if a price on apples could be null or sizing of price column is greater on orange.

Comment: Cool, like this one too. Thanks